# Acknowledged receipt of canvas death jme3

Tags: lwjgl, jmonkeyengine

I am using JmonkeyEngine SDk 3 to develop a software simulation program.

To cut the story short, I created a canvas in an internal frame  inside a swing Jframe object.
when I close the internal frame I remove all its components, then I get that message in the log screen

**"May 29, 2013 2:48:29 PM com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglCanvas$GLCanvas removeNotify
INFO: EDT: Acknowledged receipt of canvas death"**

and then my java application stops responding to any other commands.

Any help with removing the canvas safely?